# Extract numbers from string doesnt work! c

Tags: c, string, strtol

i would remove the "-" from the ISBN String.
But my code dont print me the value out. Where is the fault?

```
char *ISBN[20];  //example: 3-423-62167-2
*p = ISBN;

strcpy(ISBN, ptr); //Copy from a Buffer
printf("\nISBN Array: %s", ISBN); //This works!

while(*p)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        printf("%ld\n", val);         //Do not show anything!
    }
    else
    {
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the declaration of `p`?

Comment: `char *ISBN[20]`? Sure? Array of array?

Comment: just `char ISBN[20]` is enough. There you have an array of C-strings

Comment: @Adriano no, that's an array of pointers.

Comment: Also, @OP: `strtol()` doesn't do what you think it does. **Read its documentation.**

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, just let me call `char*` a C-style string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrectly using `strtol` is unnecessary; the 2nd argument is not an input, but an output i.e. it sets it to the last interpreted character. Above all, why do you want to convert the character to a long and then convert it back again to a character, when all you need is a character to print?

```
char ISBN[] = "3-423-62167-2";
char *p = ISBN;
while (*p)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
        printf("%c", *p);
    ++p;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To make the whole string into a long:

```
unsigned long long num = 0;
while (*p)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        const char digit = *p - '0';
        num = (num * 10) + digit;
    }
    ++p;
}
```

Comment: I need to convert the ISBN String to long without the "-" to work with that in a Modulo Operation. But with your example i only print the String out. How i can do that?

Comment: You mean each digit as a `long` or the whole _3423621672_ as `long`?

Comment: whole long: 3423621672

Comment: First of all, with a (signed) `long` of 4 bytes you can only represent upto _2147483647_; with an `unsigned long` of 4 bytes you can represent upto _4294967295_. What would you do when the ISBN number is _8-423-62167-2_?

Comment: @user3214376: I'd say you should go with `unsigned long long` which is guarenteed to be atleast 64-bits which can represent upto _18446744073709551615_. Updated the answer with the solution but make sure you aren't running in to [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: How i can reset the *p to let him do the loop again, after i changed my ISBN String?

Comment: Can you please be more specific and clear? I'm unable to understand you.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
for (char* p = ISBN; *p != '\0'; p++)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
}
```

If you want a `long`: Save the characters in a `char[]` (instead of `printf()`) and then, when done, convert that to a `long`.  You could even use your `ISBN` array to do an in-place convert:

```
int i = 0;
for (char* p = ISBN; *p != '\0'; p++)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        ISBN[i++] = *p;
    }
}

ISBN[i] = '\0';

long isbn = strtol(ISBN, NULL, 10);
```

BTW, you forgot `p++` when `is digit()` is true.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char *ptr = "3-423-62167-2";
char ISBN[20];  // should be either ISBN[] or char *ISBN for a string
char *p = ISBN; // declared this one here.. else should be p = ISBN

strcpy(ISBN, ptr);
printf("\nISBN Array: %s\n", ISBN);

while(*p)
{
    if (isdigit(*p))
    {
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        printf("%ld\n", val);
    }
    else
    {
        p++;
    }
}

}
```

Have marked the corrections in the comments!

Comment: Thank you all! The answers are all useful! But how i can safe the new value as long and work with that?

Comment: @legends2k: why would that be? "3-423-62167-2" is a null-terminated string hence (*p) is a good enough exit condition..

Comment: This code will extract the numbers separately; if you only want to get rid of the hyphens and convert the combined number into long then the answer from @meaning-matters is the one you want.

Comment: OK, I was wrong about the infinite loop, but you need to also include _ctype.h_ and _stdlib.h_ too. I upvoted you.

Comment: @legends2k: agree with that.. gcc didn't warn me though.

Comment: @th33lf: It did warn me when I invoked it as `-Wall -pedantic -std=c11`.

Comment: @legends2k: yes, i should've used -Wall. am curious what made you suspect it to be wrong?

Comment: Having `p++` only inside the `else`, what I missed was the `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p` is `char *` pointer you should update your code to

```
//-----v no *
  char ISBN[20];  //example: 3-423-62167-2
  p = ISBN;
//^-- no *
```

keep rest of the code as is.

Comment: Also, `strtol()` doesn't do what OP thinks it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP wants is to convert a string with hyphens to a long integer. This function converts the decimal digits of a string to a long. Hyphens (in any place) are ignored, other characters, including space, lead to a reading error:

```
/*
 *      Return ISBN as long or -1L on format error
 */
long isbn(const char *str)
{
    long n = 0L;

    if (*str == '\0') return -1L;

    while (*str) {
        if (isdigit(*str)) {
            n = n * 10 + *str - '0';
        } else {
            if (*str != '-') return -1L;
        }
        str++;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Note that a `long` has the same size as an `int` on some machines and may not be wide enough to store a numeric ISBN.